# Google DeepMind Wavenet voices in mac TTS?

Tags: macos, google, text-to-speech

I don't know enough about code to do this, but is it possible to use the Google wavenet voices in the Mac TTS? Under System Preferences > Accessibility > Speech you can chose voices and if you download more, you can use those voices to listen to things. I was hoping that there's a way to listen to things using the WaveNet ones.

Here's some documentation: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol

I know they've been integrated to Chrome Extensions.